I keep getting error in Proteus. The project is a dual power supply
[SPICE] DELMIN increased to 5.55112e-017 due to lack of time precision
[SPICE] transient GMIN stepping at time=0.361875
[SPICE] TRAN:  Timestep too small; timestep = 6.93889e-018: trouble with instance BR1_D1.



Just look at the problems I see in the circuit: -

I'm not going to list them because they are basic errors and you should take more care when putting a schematic together.

Thank you, I realized I didn't connect the ground, the IC input and output should have been mirrored, and the IC for the negative voltage should have been 7912 IC
